# Error in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm writing programs with a simple Fragment and I got an error as below:

```
FrameLayout fl=new FrameLayout(this);
fl.setId(0x1024);

setContentView(fl);
FragmentTransaction ftransc=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FragmentTest2 myFragment=new FragmentTest2();
ftransc.add(fl.getId(), myFragment, "FirstFragment");
ftransc.commit();
```

Under the `add` method I get a red squiggly line and the following error shows:

> The method `add(int, Fragment, String` in the type `FragmentTransaction` is not applicable for the arguments `(int, FragmentTest2, String)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your FragmentTest2 extend Fragment?

Answer (score 5):

This problem usually occurs when you mix up the compatibility package `Fragment` and the Android `Fragment`.  If you are trying to use the compatibility Fragment, make sure that you import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, otherwise make sure you import `android.app.Fragment`.  Similarly do the same with `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: can we use both in same class ?