# The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment, String)

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have this problem ..

```
The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment, String)
```

when using the following code inside a `FragenmtActivity`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(com.korovyansk.android.slideout.R.id.slideout_placeholder,  ((Fragment)new CommentsMenuFragment()), "menu").commit();
```

where CommentsMenuFragment implementation is :

```
public class CommentsMenuFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comment, container, false);
        ListView lvComments = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvComments);



        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use android.support.v4.app.Fragment or android.app.Fragment?

Comment: Thanks I've found the answer for it in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753921/error-in-fragment

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check if your CommentsMenuFragment extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of  android.app.Fragment.

Comment: it helped me, my Fragment was imported be android.app.fragment, I changed the import to android.support.v4.app, and the add error of my FragmentActivity Disapeared. Thanks @PaNaVTEC